# ¿Por qué si hago un print a una variable me retorna lo que quiero, pero si hago un return(variable) me retorna solo el primer dígito?

Tags: python

Quiero crear una función la cual te retorne un número sin su último dígito, ejemplo: 456 te retorna 4 y 5.

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es esto:

```
def sacarultimodigito(num):
    for elem in str(num):
        if elem!=(str(num)[-1]):
            print (elem)



print(sacarultimodigito(456))
```

Mi pregunta es que no entiendo por qué si le hago un `print` a *elem* me retorna lo que quiero, pero si le hago un `return(elem)` me retorna solo el primer dígito.

Comment: La función  `print` no hace lo mismo que la palabra reservada `return`. La sentencia `return` "corta" la ejecución del código y retorna inmediatamente el valor, por esta razón tu ciclo no llega a terminarse y todo se termina en la primera interacción del ciclo lo que conlleva a que se retorne solo el primer dígito. Tu código se pude simplificar a `return int(str(num)[:-1])`

Comment: me podrías explicar un poco más sobre los dos puntos?, cuándo ponerlos a la derecha y cuándo a la izquierda

Comment: Es la sintaxis de *slicing* que permite obtener un pedazo de un iterable. La sintaxis completa es `obj[inicio :fin :paso]` si se omite el inicio por defecto es `0`, el fin sería el largo del iterable y el paso `1`. En el caso de `str(num)[:-1]` se toma desde el inicio ( por defecto 0) hasta `longitud del iterable  - 1`

Answer (score 1):

La forma matemática es simplemente una **división entera** `//` del número entre `10`.

```
def elim_ult_digito_mat(num):
    return num // 10
```

La forma usando operaciones de cadena, sería convirtiendo el número, y luego haciendo un slice desde el principio al final -1. En este caso fallaría si el número solo tiene un dígito. Para corregirlo se usa un `if` que evalúa si el número es menor que `10` y devolverá `0` en ese caso.

```
def elim_ult_digito_str(num):
    return 0 if num < 10 else int(str(num)[:-1])
```

Probando las dos funciones, se obtiene el mismo resultado:

```
print(elim_ult_digito_mat(3278)) # 327
print(elim_ult_digito_str(3278)) # 327
print(elim_ult_digito_mat(6)) # 0
print(elim_ult_digito_str(6)) # 0
```